# How to make fake Url with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a fake path for a my location files on the web.
For example, my file is in address:

```
root\a\b.jpg
```

but I want to show:

```
root\{ 16 Random Character } b.jpg
```

In fact for greater security. The same as dropbox sharing.

Comment: Exactly how does this result in "greater security"?  Define the actual purpose of what you're trying to accomplish and there may be a specific way to achieve that goal.

Comment: "in fact for greater security."

Comment: try url rewriting concept

Comment: Have a look at "url rewrite iis"

Comment: Security through obscurity is not security.

Comment: @David I think this is pretty self-explanatory. He wants to limit file downloads to certain people so actual file URL won't be shown.

Comment: If you don't want to reveal any path information, don't show the path information at all. Regardless of whether or not someone knows where the actual file is, they should only be able to retrieve the file through whatever mechanism you give them, if security is important. For example, people often store the files on a remote file system, and, instead, the end user will call a URL which, during processing retrieves that file and writes it to the client.

Comment: This could very easily be accomplished by simply having a sort of "gateway" page which accepts an identifier for a file and some kind of key that was given to the user.  Validate that the key is good for that file, and return the file.  No need for URL rewriting.

Comment: @David Exactly, hence my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to generate random folder, you just need to pass file binary data to browser so it will download it without showing the actual location of said file. [More info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654).

Short example

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Set the appropriate ContentType.
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";

    //Get the physical path to the file.
    string FilePath = MapPath("acrobat.pdf");

    //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
    Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
    Response.End();
}
```